# Employee does not show on pivot view (odoo12)

Tags: python, odoo

I can't display the employee_id value in a  pivot view . I get undefined.
[image]

```
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', "Employees")


  <record id="view_hr_employee_pivot" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.mymodel.pivot</field>
        <field name="model">hr.mymodel</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <pivot string="Employee " display_quantity="true">
                  <field name="employee_id" type="row"/>
            </pivot>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have values in employee_id field on your table hr.mymodel. If there is no value then odoo will show undefined always.